# Android: Fast rotate CameraPreview

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I am building Face detection app using OpenCv. I am processing preview frame data received on callback onPreviewFrame. I am using camera in portrait mode, whereas onPreviewFrame returns me data in landscape mode. I am rotating frame data using this code.

```
public static byte[] rotateYUV420Degree90(byte[] data, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) {
    byte[] yuv = new byte[imageWidth * imageHeight * 3 / 2];
    // Rotate the Y luma
    int i = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++) {
        for (int y = imageHeight - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
            yuv[i] = data[y * imageWidth + x];
            i++;
        }
    }
    // Rotate the U and V color components
    i = imageWidth * imageHeight * 3 / 2 - 1;
    for (int x = imageWidth - 1; x > 0; x = x - 2) {
        for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight / 2; y++) {
            yuv[i] = data[(imageWidth * imageHeight) + (y * imageWidth) + x];
            i--;
            yuv[i] = data[(imageWidth * imageHeight) + (y * imageWidth) + (x - 1)];
            i--;
        }
    }
    return yuv;
}
```

After rotating data, I am converting to byte array to OpenCv Mat. After the conversion I pass into openCv native code.

In landscape mode (without rotating preview data), I am able to get almost 20 FPS after processing camera preview. But in portrait mode, with above method, the FPS is reduced to 3 FPS. On measuring time taken by `rotateYUV420Degree90`, this method is the main culprit.

I am new to OpenCv. Is there any other approach that i can take to rotate preview data using java code or native code, fastly. Because of complexity of my app, i cannot use `JavaCameraView` provided by OpenCV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem: Dont traverse image in column-order. Since, you are not benefited by locality of reference, the code will run very slow.

For opencv, you can use combination of transpose and flip command.

```
switch (angle) {
        case 0:
            srcImage.copyTo(dstImage);
            break;
        case 90:
            Core.transpose(srcImage, dstImage);
            Core.flip(dstImage, dstImage, 1);
            break;
        case 180:
            Core.flip(srcImage, dstImage, -1);
            break;
        case 270:
            Core.transpose(srcImage, dstImage);
            Core.flip(dstImage, dstImage, 0);
            break;
        default:
            Logger.error(
                "ROTATE_IMAGE_CLOCKWISE: Incorrect rotation value received: {}", 
                angle);
            return srcImage;
    }
```

This is the same code used to read input image when Image(jpeg) has Orientation metadata. See opencv source code [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/91d8405e52c186af90a0f8df9c0a147925552bc2/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_jpeg.cpp#L305). The above code is in java.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40055711/1874627), to know how orientation works. Put opencv and the image from my answer together, and its very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already an answer in this:

[Android: How to rotate a bitmap on a center point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166917/android-how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-on-a-center-point)

in your case your rotation is just mRotation = 90 degrees.